# Sending message programmatically with swift

Tags: swift, message

This code opens the message app and sends the message. Unfortunately the messaging app does not close. Always have to kill the app. The message app gets bugged down. The cancel button does not work. Any help is appreciated.

Picture 1: This is the initial screen. Cancel is available and everything seems normal

Picture 2: This is after hitting return so the message is sent. Noice the Cancel option is grey out

Picture 3: This is the crash. Keyboard is gone, cancel is still gray out and there is no way to close this window

```
import SwiftUI
import MessageUI

struct Services: View {


@Binding var name: String
let urlString = URL (string: "tel://1234567")!

var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView{
        VStack {
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
            
            Text("text1" )
            .padding(.vertical, 5.0)                
            }
            
            Spacer()

            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    
                    UIApplication.shared.open(self.urlString)
                    
                }) {
                    Text("Call phone")
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 150)
                .font(.subheadline)
                
                Button(action: {
                    presentMessageCompose(name: self.name)

                }) {
                    Text("Text phone")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 150)
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Title")
    }
}

}

func presentMessageCompose(name:String) {

let messageComposeDelegate = MessageComposeDelegate()

guard MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() else {
    return
}
let vc = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first?.rootViewController

let composeVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
composeVC.messageComposeDelegate = messageComposeDelegate
composeVC.recipients = ["1234567"]
composeVC.body = "Message to send to \(name))"
vc?.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I had to create this class separate: MessageComposeDelegate

```
 import Foundation
 import MessageUI


 class MessageComposeDelegate: NSObject, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {
func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {
    // Customize here
    controller.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

}

[image]

[image]

[image]

I moved the code related to opening the message to a new class:

```
 import UIKit
 import MessageUI

 class DisplayMessageInterface: UIViewController, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {
   
func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {
    switch (result) {
        case .cancelled:
            print("Message was cancelled")
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        case .failed:
            print("Message failed")
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        case .sent:
            print("Message was sent")
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        default:
        break
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func displayMessageInterface() {
    let topVC = topMostController()
    let composeVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
    composeVC.messageComposeDelegate = self
    
    // Configure the fields of the interface.
    composeVC.recipients = ["1234567"]
    composeVC.body = "I love Swift!"
    
    // Present the view controller modally.
    if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() {
        topVC.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        print("Can't send messages.")
    }
}
func topMostController() -> UIViewController {
var topController: UIViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!
    while (topController.presentedViewController != nil) {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController!
    }
    return topController
}
```

}

and updated the button action to:

```
 Button(action: {
                    let displaymessageinterface = DisplayMessageInterface()
                    
                    displaymessageinterface.displayMessageInterface()
                })
```

but still I get the same problem

When I hit the Cancel button a new error appears: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1c)". Picture 4

[image]

Comment: You cannot have the Mail app automatically send a message.  It would be scary if you could do it without user's awareness.

Comment: Instead of just typing in garbage, why not explain what you've done to try and solve the problem?

Comment: I have no idea what to do to solve the problem because I do not know why the code is messing with the message app and making it crash

Comment: This code does not open the email. It opens the phone to  make a call and works fine. It opens the text message iphone app but crashes it ( uses the method presentmessagecompose)

Answer (score 1):

Have you added `messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult:` method to know when the user has finished composing the message?

https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/send-imessage-ios-tutorial

```
func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {
    switch (result) {
        case .cancelled:
            print("Message was cancelled")
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        case .failed:
            print("Message failed")
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        case .sent:
            print("Message was sent")
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here

https://medium.com/@florentmorin/messageui-swiftui-and-uikit-integration-82d91159b0bd

keywindow is deprecated:

Replace: let vc = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController

with: let vc = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter { $0.isKeyWindow }.first?.rootViewController!